# Problema con While mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente problema, no se como hacer un while en codeigniter para el siguiente ejemplo(este lo hice en php orientado a objetos, en una clase, y lo llamaba en un listboxt en el diseño)

```
function lista_sucursales(){

 $opciones="";
 $sql="SELECT * FROM sucursales";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);

 while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    $id_suc=$datos["id_suc"];
    $nombre_suc=$datos["nombre_suc"];
    $opciones.="<option value='$id_suc'>$nombre_suc</option>";

  }
    return ($opciones);
 }
```

Estoy tratando de hacerlo en un model pero no funciona(se que esta mal, pero en realidad no se como hacerlo...)

```
 <?php

 class mHorarios extends CI_Model
 {

  function __construct()
  {
   parent::__construct();
  }

  public function lista_jc ()
  {

  $opciones="";


  $this->db->select('rut_usu,pnombre,apellido_pa,apellido_ma');
  $this->db->from('usuarios');


  while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($this->load->database)) {

  $rut_usu=$datos["rut_usu"];
  $pnombre=$datos["pnombre"];
  $apellido_pa=$datos["apellido_pa"];
  $apellido_ma=$datos["apellido_ma"];

  $opciones.="<option value='$rut_usu'>$pnombre." ".$apellido_pa." 
  ".$apellido_ma</option>";

   }
   return ($opciones);


  }


 }

 ?>
```

Comment: No deberias usar un while en tu modelo...creo que deberias retornar algo como `return $this->db->get();`

Comment: mmm...me podrías dar una explicación más extensa? hace poco comencé con codeigniter....

Comment: Modelo, vista, controlador. El modelo retorna un ser de datos al controlador, este inyecta esos datos a la vista, y en la vista creas el select iterando sobre el ser de datos. O bien retorna el ser de datos desde el controlador como json, consume el método con ajax, y pimba.